# Definition of the ring of differentiable maps $C^\infty(M)$, where $M$ is a differentiable manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold. We define the set $C^{\infty}(M) := \{f : M \to \mathbb{R} \text{ differentiable}\}$.

We can endow this set with a ring structure considering the common sum of functions:

$$(f+g)(p) := f(p)+g(p)$$

and the product (instead of the composition):

$$(fg)(p) := f(p)g(p)$$

So, the neutral element for $+$ is the constant map zero, and the neutral element for the product is the constant map $1$ or the identity map? (then is a domain?)

Or we consider $(C^{\infty}(M),+,\circ)$ with $\circ$ the composition of differentiable maps?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you compose two maps from $M \to \mathbb R$? Both maps act on elements of $M$, not $\mathbb R$. So composition is out of the question. The first notion is therefore the correct one.

Comment: This is basically formalising the idea that the pointwise sum and product of any two $C^\infty$ functions is again a $C^\infty$ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ is an arbitrary differentiable manifold, so the "identity map" does not make sense unless $M$ itself is $\mathbb{R}$. So, the multiplicative identity is the constant map $1$.

Again, since $M$ is an arbitrary differentiable manifold, composition does not necessarily make sense. It only makes sense if $M = \mathbb{R}$. So, composition cannot in general define a multiplication on $C^\infty(M)$.

The question

> (then is a domain?)

does not make sense to me. Are you perhaps asking if $C^\infty(M)$ is an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain)? If so, the answer is **no**, and it is a good exercise to find two nonzero smooth functions on $M$ whose product is the zero function.

Comment: It´s not integral domain because for $f,g$ defined as $f(x)=0, x <0$ and $f(x)=\sin(x),x \leq 0$; $g(x)=\sin(x),x < 0$ and $g(x)=0, x \geq 0$ we get $f(x)g(x)=0$ but $f,g$ are non-zero functions, right?

Comment: @user540275 There are two problems with your example. The first is that it is specialised to the case $M = \mathbb{R}$. It would be better to produce an example for the case of an arbitrary differentiable manifold rather than only for $\mathbb{R}$. Secondly, the functions $f$ and $g$ are not differentiable at $0$, they are only continuous at $0$. But the idea is more or less accurate. Try $f(x) = e^{-x^{-2}}$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$, and $g(x)$ appropriately as you had done. Then try to see if the same example generalises to an arbitrary manifold $M$.